# Dynamic Control used to create Link Button and assign properties on ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind, linkbutton, dynamic-controls

I would like to generate the Link Button as below in code behind.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCustomize" OnClientClick="showDialog('editPerson')" Text="Customize"  CommandName="Customize"  CommandArgument='<%#Eval("type") + ";" + Eval("facility") + ";" + Eval("timestamp")%>runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
```

This is what I have so far but failed to retrieve value from arguements. Appreciate for any reply.

```
LinkButton link = new LinkButton();
link.Text = "Customize";
link.ID = "lnkCustomize";
double timestamp = ConvertToUnixTimestamp(leftstartTime1);
link.CommandArgument = Eval("type") + "," + Eval("facility") + "," + Eval("timestamp");
link.Command += new CommandEventHandler(DynamicClick);
link.OnClientClick = "showDialog('editPerson')";
```

Comment: Do you ever add it to the page's Controls list?

Comment: yes, the link button presented but just cannot work properly

Comment: This is somewhat out of context. Where do you want to create the LinkButton dynamically? And what does this mean: "_failed to retrieve value from arguements_"? Normally you would use the DataSource directly(f.e. `e.Row.DataItem` in `RowDataBound` of a GridView).

Comment: @TimSchmelter from the code behind and the failure is cannot extract the value passed from parameters since I guess there is something wrong with my coding on link.CommandArguement.

Comment: @SƲmmēr Aƥ: From _codebehind_ does not tell from where at all. The failure is "cannot extract value passed from parameters"?? Do you get an exception, have you debugged? Do you have a DataSource here that you could use directly instead?

Comment: @TimSchmelter, in the Page_Load. And I got this error message from exception. "Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control."

Comment: @SƲmmēr: I must repeat a third time, can you use the DataSource directly? Where do you add this LinkButton to(f.e. any databound control like Repeater,FormView,...)? What datasource  and what control are you using at all? So why not communicate these informations at the first place?

Comment: I got the actual format to define commandArguement already. Anyway, thanks for your concern.

Comment: Please rewrite this, removing the FIXED, and answering the question with the solution you found. You can then mark your own answer as correct.

Comment: @Guvante I did make changes already and how i gonna mark my own answer as correct?

Comment: You need to enter your answer in the "Your answer" section below. Then you should have the ability to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Fixed by having proper defined format**

```
link.CommandArgument = "first_parameter_value_goes_here" + "," + "second_parameter_value_goes_here" + "," + "third_parameter_value_goes_here";
```

**2. Fixed by extracting all the values of arguements as below**

```
public void DynamicClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var editLink = ((LinkButton)sender);
        string info = editLink.CommandArgument;
        string[] arg = new string[2];
        char[] splitter = { ',' };
        arg = info.Split(splitter);
        var var1 = arg[0];
        var var2 = arg[1];
        var var3 = arg[2];
    }
```